# How does SQL server compress NULL bit datatypes?

Tags: sql-server, bit

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can Microsoft store three-valued fields in a single bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2954718/can-microsoft-store-three-valued-fields-in-a-single-bit)

According to the [documentation for bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx), the bit datatype can have three values, 0, 1 and NULL *and* if there are 8 or less bit columns in a table, those columns will be compressed into one byte.

These two behaviors seem contradictory. If so, which part is correct, the ability of a bit to be NULL or the compression of 8 bits to a byte?

Comment: I would hazard a guess that this only applies to non-nullable BIT columns.

Comment: that was an exact duplicate, I voted to close too

Answer (score 2):

NULL values are handled by a separate bit for each column (for example look [here](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/09/06/How_does_SQL_Server_really_store_NULL-s.aspx) for details).